# How to change form size at runtime by a button in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

nothing seems to be working, most of the questions asked here about this was given a simple answer `this.width` or a reference to the form then `formNamevariable.width`, even `scale` isn't working
any help please?

Comment: Which Form? Any? The current Form's instance (`this`)? -- What size? The size of the Client Area or the overall Window size (including borders and Caption)? -- What isn't working? The Window size doesn't change? The resulting size doesn't match the value you have set? Is your app DpiAware?

Answer (score 0):

You have `not tagged any language` and it is not clear what language you are working with. But from the appearance of the question, it is probably C#.

try this:

```
this.Size = new Size(400, 400);
```

Comment: i tagged c#, i tried this and it didnt work as well

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution:

1. i gotta give my form the full size it might become from the size property.
2. in the "Load", i give it the start size i want (which must be smaller so i can resize it to any bigger size) by the code

   this.ClientSize = new system.drawing.size (x,y)

worked like a charm.